# Why Bootstrap navbar-brand is not on the right spot

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the regular bootstrap navbar. The problem is that the item navbar-brand is higher than the rest of the items in the navbar. It does not make any sense. It does not happen on the bootstrap page. I tried the code on jsfriddle an same problem. This is how the bar looks like:

[image]

And here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="templates/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/svjdL9bt/embedded/result/

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels I changed the version of bootstrap to the same you are running on jsfiddle and it works. I was using the last version avaliable of bootsrap. Why is it happenning?

Comment: Updated to BS 3.3.2. I'm still not seeing it: http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/svjdL9bt/5/embedded/result/

Comment: what browser are you using? ( I'm still not seeing it . i use chrome and Bootstrap v3.0.0 ).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the different alignment might be because you have a css property or properties that override your bootstrap css.

Check your custom css file and remove anything that has `.navbar-header` or `.navbar-brand` on it and see if that helps.