# Navbar-brand is off center and improperly sized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, aurelia

This seems to be a [common](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28164682/206466) [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37218850/206466). I don't have any custom css, and right now I'm not using collapse (maybe that's my problem?), how can I fix my html so that bootstrap has the brand laid out right? whilst retaining my right floating/wrapping login form.

[image: image of navbar]

```
<template>
    <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">RPF</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-right container-fluid">
                    <form show.bind="!isAuthenticated()" class="navbar-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
                            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
                        </div>
                        <button name="login" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign In</button>
                        <button name="register" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Register</button>
                    </form>
                    <form show.bind="isAuthenticated()" class="navbar-form">
                        <button name="logout" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign Out</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="row container">
        <nav class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="#">Manage Content</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main id="content" class="container-fluid">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
```

p.s Aurelia isn't particularly relevant, but that's what the extra syntax is from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is primarily due to the use of the `navbar-btn` class inside a `navbar-form`: see [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons)

> Add the `.navbar-btn` class to `<button>` elements not residing in a
>   `<form>` to vertically center them in the navbar.

You also should not need this div `<div class="navbar-right container-fluid">` around your form, use `<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">` as well as avoid combining `container`s with `row`s in a single div: `<div class="row container">` or nesting containers. See [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

**Working Example:** *Open at FullPage*

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RPF</a>
      </div>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
          <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
        </div>
        <button name="login" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
        <button name="register" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
      </form>
      <!-- <form show.bind="isAuthenticated()" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <button name="logout" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sign Out</button>
      </form>-->

    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#">Manage Content</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <main id="content">
    <router-view>VIEW</router-view>
  </main>

</div>
```

Comment: with the row what I'm trying to do is have a full length left side nav, and content just to the right of it. I will probably allow nav to auto hide at some point similar to material design (like google inbox). Perhaps there's a better way to do that. I could address that as a 2nd question though.

Comment: Im not sure I see why combining a row and container into one div is necessary for that. Either way hopefully this solved the main issue you're having.

Comment: it probably isn't, maybe I misunderstood what you're saying about the row and container, but yes solves my main issue

Answer (score 0):

as you included

```
RPF
```

in navbar-header so it will be from left side only. you have to add css and make it important by !important. so that your changes will be considered by browser

Comment: huh? the left/right thing is working right now. the problem is that RPF is not centered in the navbar and from looking at the examples I'd say the font is smaller than it should be. I mean I could use css to fix this, but that seems likely to be wrong

Comment: you are using form-control class which by default leave 6 pixel from top. can you add 6 pixel padding to RDF